# “VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path”

Tags: linux, virtualbox, docker

I'm getting the error:

Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

When trying to create a vm in terminal. I've uninstalled and reinstalled virtualbox, Ive confirmed VBoxManage exists.

Comment: Can you check the output of `which VBoxManage` or `type VBoxManage` from the same terminal?

Comment: Output of 'type VboxManage' is VBoxManage is /usr/bin/VBoxManage.  Output of 'which VBoxManage'  was nothing.

Comment: Actually the output for 'which VBoxManage' was: /usr/bin/VBoxManage

Comment: Please edit the question to add information instead of answering the comments directly. Have you tried running the VBoxManage command with sudo/root?

Comment: Editing the question with the answer was rejected. But I have also tried with sudo/root.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on ubuntu 18.04, had installed docker using snap
i removed that and installed docker and docker-compse using apt
and docker-machine using:

```
$ base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
  curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/tmp/docker-machine &&
  sudo install /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

difference is snap will install docker-machine v0.15 and we will be installing v0.16